# MongoDB: duplicate documents in collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm new in mongodb and can't find the solution.

I'm using [mongo-php-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver)

I just created some collection.
I want to create some document from PHP code.

```
$collection->create(array(
    'asda'=>12312,
    'cxzcxz'=>'czczcxz'
));
```

When that code works, there are two same records in collection, with different _id.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff4b3b8859183d41700000f"), "asda" : 12312, "cxzcxz" : "czczcxz" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ff4b3b8859183d417000010"), "asda" : 12312, "cxzcxz" : "czczcxz" }
```

How to fix it, and what I need to change here to have only one document?

I have _id index in table. Maybe I need to set this key every time? When i setted _id field, it saved one record in collection. But how to make it auto (like auto increment) ?

Comment: specify what library you are using to connect to mongoDB from php

Comment: that. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads from official mongo docs

Comment: shouldn't be insert instead of create?

Comment: insert not help. same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to insert more than one record with similar information because you have not specified a unique index on any of those values.  The [default unique index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-The%5CidIndex) will be on `_id`.

You can define your own index from PHP using [MongoCollection.ensureIndex](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.ensureindex.php) eg:

```
// create a unique index on 'phonenum'
$collection->ensureIndex(array('phonenum' => 1), array("unique" => true));
```

It's also worth reading the MongoDB documentation on [unique indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue) as there are a few caveats  to be aware of if a unique index is being created for an existing collection that may already have duplicates or null values.

You also have the option of providing your own `_id` value if there is a more natural primary key to use.  You will have to ensure that this `_id` is unique for new insertions, though.

The default [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) created by MongoDB is designed to have a reasonably high probability of being unique when allocated.

Code example:

```
<?php

// Connect to MongoDB server
$mongo = new Mongo();

// Use database 'mydb' and collection 'mycoll'
$collection = $mongo->mydb->mycoll;

// Drop this collection for TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
$collection->drop();

// The document details to insert
$document = array(
    'asda' => 12312,
    'cxzcxz' => 'czczcxz',
);

try {
    $collection->insert($document, array("safe" => true));

    // Note that $collection->insert() adds the _id of the document inserted
    echo "Saved with _id:", $document['_id'], "\n";
}
catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
}

// Add unique index for field 'asda'
$collection->ensureIndex(array('asda' => 1), array("unique" => true));

// Try to insert the same document again
$document = array(
    'asda' => 12312,
    'cxzcxz' => 'czczcxz',
);
try {
    $collection->insert($document, array("safe" => true));
    echo "Saved with _id:", $document['_id'], "\n";
}
catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can I do auto_increment field? Or something like that. To add some record to collection I will need to know new id, how to get it?

Comment: MongoDB's ObjectID serves a similar purpose to an auto-increment field: provide an automatically generated unique identifier.  Once your data starts being distributed across multiple servers via [replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets#ReplicaSets-Overview) and [sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction) the concept of a centralized auto-increment number sequence is no longer relevant if you want writes to happen independently within your cluster.

Comment: @NikitaKuhta if you don't provide an `_id` when inserting a new document, a default ObjectID will be assigned.  This is exactly what you are seeing in your example query in the original post .. you inserted two records and default ObjectIDs were added by the MongoDB server.

Comment: And it inserted TWO records, with different ObjectID. I want to add only one record, and I don't want to set any other unique index. Is it possible, or I need to set some another id field necessarily?

Comment: I mean, that I use create (or insert) method only one time, and in collection inserts two records instead of one. I will watch unique logic by PHP scripts, but first I need to add only one record insead of two.

Comment: @NikitaKuhta what uniqueness criteria do you want to enforce?  You need to decide on this to avoid inserting duplicates.  If you want to provide your [own _id](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) field, that's fine too.  An auto increment or default ObjectID will add uniqueness, but doesn't prevent you from inserting almost identical documents with different _ids.

Comment: I mean, that I will watch uniquess by PHP. I don't want to use some keys in database. I have another problem.

When I want to add record (one time!!!), i call my create method. DB must to add that record ONE TIME. And then there need to be ONE that record in collection. I understand, that if I will run script twice, there will be two same records. But I call script ONCE, and there is only one "create" method worked. And after this I see TWO same records. Why? I had only one create method worked. Why mongo added two records, instead one?

Comment: After normal adding, I will check uniquess in another way. But for start I need to create one record at first script running.

Comment: @NikitaKuhta: added a code example.  Beyond that you should really study the [MongoDB PHP driver tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) and module documentation.